# "When I am in Berlin" or "when I will be in Berlin"?

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct?

1. Maybe we could visit the Bundestag when I am in Berlin.
2. Maybe we could visit the Bundestag when I will be in Berlin.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Welcome. This question may be better suited to [ELL.se]. It might get closed here. We want to see evidence that you researched the issue before you asked here. What did you investigate, and what did you find? Oh, and please take the site [tour].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. is correct. Future tense is not used after temporal conjunctions. No question mark is required.

Comment: Both "am" and "will" are in the exact same tense (present). So both 1. and 2. are equally correct according to your own rule. Which I doubt is a rule in the first place.

Comment: It is not my rule as you said. The present simple is used in clauses introduced by when, as soon as, until, after, before and while.